# Permission Denied - Django Deployment on Ubuntu 16.04 with web server Nginx

Tags: 16.04, nginx, django, uwsgi

I am trying to deploy a django website on a Ubuntu 16.04 system using nginx but I am having issues.

**ERRORS**

Error I get from my nginx `error.log` file:

```
connect() to unix:/home/teddycrepineau/contoursandcolors/contoursandcolors.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 64.125.191.37, server: 173.255.210.63, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/teddycrepineau/contoursandcolors/contoursandcolors.sock:", host: "173.255.210.63", referrer: "http://173.255.210.63/"
```

Status of `uwgsi`:

```
$ uwsgi status
uwsgi[25361]: thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi[25361]: uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /home/teddycrepineau/contoursandcolors/contoursandcolors.sock fd 3
uwsgi[25361]: Python version: 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
uwsgi[25361]: !!! Python Home is not a directory: /home/teddycrepineau/Env/contoursandcolors !!!
uwsgi[25361]: Set PythonHome to /home/teddycrepineau/Env/contoursandcolors 
uwsgi[25361]: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
uwsgi[25361]: ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
uwsgi[25361]: Current thread 0x00007f0ec8429700 (most recent call first):
uwsgi[25361]: Thu Apr 12 13:31:57 2018 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance contoursandcolors.ini (pid: 4955)
uwsgi[25361]: Thu Apr 12 13:32:00 2018 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance contoursandcolors.ini
```

**SET UP**

- Using Python 3
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Using Virtualenvwrapper and virtualenv

Virtualenvwrapper set up

```
echo "export WORKON_HOME=~/Env" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

`/etc/uwsgi/sites/contoursandcolors.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
project = contoursandcolors
uid = teddycrepineau
base = /home/%(uid)

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 2

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/contoursandcolor`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 173.255.210.63;

        location = /favicon.io { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        location /static/ {
                root /home/teddycrepineau/contoursandcolors;
        }

        location / {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/home/teddycrepineau/contoursandcolors/contoursandcolors.sock;
        }
}
```

`/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown teddycrepineau:www-data /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

- Changed default python version from 2.7 to 3.5
- Change socket file location from project to run (get me a file not found error)
- I looked at quite a few StackExchange posts, but none have resolved my issue thus far

From what I read, my issue may be related to virtualenv location set up. Where should I go from here?

---

**EDIT**

I ended up using gunicorn (instead of uWSGI). It worked fine and was pretty easy to set up. Here is the link to the tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04